# HTML two sides of a span

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a **SPAN** in a **LI** which looks likes this visually (the LI is 400px wide so there is lots of space):

```
 [Name (age)             ]
```

I want (age) to be on the right, Name on the left:

```
 [Name              (age)]
```

My code base:

```
 <li>
    <span>John Smith(30)</span>
 </li>
```

How do I get them both to **stick** to the edges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using it this way

HTML

```
<li>
<span>John Smith</span><span class="age">(30)</span>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
li{width:400px}
li span.age{float:right;}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dwebexperts/sn8Z5/1/)

Comment: this wasn't really difficult, or?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<li style="width: 200px;"><span>John Smith</span><span style="float: right;"></li>
```